Azure service bus filter on nested properties
If below is the payload for Azure service bus
{
  “type”:{
    “Number”: “true”
  },
  "customer": [{
    "name": "test",
    "number": "12334455"
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "number": "6674455"
  }
 ]
}

Can I apply filter either of correlation or sql type like below using nested object properties or dot notation?

type.Number IS NOT NULL
EXISTS({type.Number})

or complex scenarios not yet supported only simple scenarios like Number = '142'?
If complex scenarios are not supported modifying the payload to bring those filter property to the root level is one of the options, is there anything else can done to support filters on the nested object property?

Modify your payload like below for the filter to work:-
Payload:-
{
  "typeNumber": "true",
  "customer": [{
    "name": "test",
    "number": "12334455"
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "number": "6674455"
  }]
}

Filter:-
typeNumber IS NOT NULL
typeNumber = 'true'



Output:-

When I used the below payload the message was not peeked:-
{
    "typeNumber": "false",
    "customer": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "number": "NULL"
        },
        {
            "name": "test2",
            "number": "6674455"
        }
    ]
}


@siddeshdesai, will apply filter over the message body property works? as  per Microsoft documentation filters can only be applied using metadata properties of message not on the body properties.

here is microsoft documentation reference:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters#:~:text=All%20filters%20evaluate%20message%20properties.%20Filters%20can%27t%20evaluate%20the%20message%20body.

It works with the above payload and using SQL fillter

@siddeshdesai, how it is works? it should not as per microsoft documentation filter will be applied message properties Not message body here is the reference here is microsoft documentation reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters

I have also added custom properties refer here - https://i.imgur.com/zfj2wxN.png
